# Blind Image Quality Assessment meaning

Tags: image-quality

I was reading about Automatic Image Distortion Identification. There I encountered a term "BQIA". 
What does "Blind Quality Image Assessment" mean ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Have you tried Google?